# Losing connection to a webservice via https "No X509TrustManager implementation available"

Tags: java, ssl

I have a really weird issue with Java and SSL certificates. Hope someone can help.

- A web is running in a cluster of 3 identical servers
- All servers contain "Application A" which is a JSR-168 portlet.
- "Application A" uses a web service that runs on
- "Application B" also uses a web service on
- All 3 server have the SSL cert from webservices.domain.com in the keystore.

When I boot the server. Application A & B work fine on all servers. After a while (no specific timing tho) Application A goes nuts one one server, not always the same server, and stops working.

**Server #1**
Application A loses connection to the webservice saying that "No X509TrustManager implementation available" (see dump below) but Application B, talking to the same server keeps on rocking.

**Server #2**
Application A & B work perfectly.

**Server #3** 
Application A & B work perfectly.

After I restart Server #1 everything returns to normal until Application A (or B) looses connection again.

Anyone know a solution?

```
13.10.2009 17:21:45 org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils getCiphersuites
INFO: The cipher suites have not been configured, falling back to cipher suite filters.
13.10.2009 17:21:45 org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils getCiphersuites
INFO: The cipher suite filters have not been configured, falling back to default filters.
13.10.2009 17:21:45 org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils getCiphersFromList
INFO: The cipher suites have been set to SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5.  
13.10.2009 17:21:46 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
 at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:466)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:299)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:251)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
 at $Proxy406.getRobbaPlanFree(Unknown Source)
 at is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.services.GSMRobbiServiceManager.getRobbaPlanFree(GSMRobbiServiceManager.java:153)
 at is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.controller.radgjafiController.populatePreferences(radgjafiController.java:179)
 at is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.controller.radgjafiController.view(radgjafiController.java:76)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:421)
 at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:136)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:271)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:259)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleRender(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:218)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:811)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:483)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:453)
 at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:175)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletMethodCommand.render(PortletMethodCommand.java:15)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletContentCommand.render(PortletContentCommand.java:19)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletCacheCommand.render(PortletCacheCommand.java:35)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletSecurityCommand.render(PortletSecurityCommand.java:27)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.render(BaseCommandUnit.java:31)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.execute(ExecutionContext.java:20)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletCommandChain.doRender(PortletCommandChain.java:29)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletApplicationHandler.process(PortletApplicationHandler.java:234)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:91)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerDispatcher.dispatch(PortletContainerDispatcher.java:390)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerDispatcher.process(PortletContainerDispatcher.java:329)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerDispatcher.render(PortletContainerDispatcher.java:276)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerServiceImpl.render(PortletContainerServiceImpl.java:122)
 at vyre.publishing.portal.Portal.renderPortlet(Portal.java:413)
 at vyre.publishing.PortletInstance.render(PortletInstance.java:221)
 at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.generated_005ffiles.pub_005fmodule.page.page17138_jsp._jspService(page17138_jsp.java:300)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
 at vyre.delivery.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:338)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at vyre.content.search.permissions.ViewPermissionFilter.doFilter(ViewPermissionFilter.java:27)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:170)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
 at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:150)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1476)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:174)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:168)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:847)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:106)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:495)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:433)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:815)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1025)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1038)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:402)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1836)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1794)
 at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
 at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1854)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:595)
 at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
 ... 89 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:322)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:840)
 ... 107 more
ERROR [TP-Processor15]: Got unknown error - is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.controller.radgjafiController - 2009-10-13 17:21:46,355 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message.
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
 at $Proxy406.getRobbaPlanFree(Unknown Source)
 at is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.services.GSMRobbiServiceManager.getRobbaPlanFree(GSMRobbiServiceManager.java:153)
 at is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.controller.radgjafiController.populatePreferences(radgjafiController.java:179)
 at is.somestuff.companyx.ut.radgjafar.radgjafi.controller.radgjafiController.view(radgjafiController.java:76)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:421)
 at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:136)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:271)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:259)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleRender(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:218)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:811)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:483)
 at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:453)
 at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:175)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletMethodCommand.render(PortletMethodCommand.java:15)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletContentCommand.render(PortletContentCommand.java:19)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletCacheCommand.render(PortletCacheCommand.java:35)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletSecurityCommand.render(PortletSecurityCommand.java:27)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.executeNextUnit(ExecutionContext.java:26)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.render(BaseCommandUnit.java:31)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.BaseCommandUnit.execute(BaseCommandUnit.java:24)
 at org.exoplatform.container.component.ExecutionContext.execute(ExecutionContext.java:20)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.aop.PortletCommandChain.doRender(PortletCommandChain.java:29)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletApplicationHandler.process(PortletApplicationHandler.java:234)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:91)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerDispatcher.dispatch(PortletContainerDispatcher.java:390)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerDispatcher.process(PortletContainerDispatcher.java:329)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerDispatcher.render(PortletContainerDispatcher.java:276)
 at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerServiceImpl.render(PortletContainerServiceImpl.java:122)
 at vyre.publishing.portal.Portal.renderPortlet(Portal.java:413)
 at vyre.publishing.PortletInstance.render(PortletInstance.java:221)
 at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.generated_005ffiles.pub_005fmodule.page.page17138_jsp._jspService(page17138_jsp.java:300)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
 at vyre.delivery.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:338)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at vyre.content.search.permissions.ViewPermissionFilter.doFilter(ViewPermissionFilter.java:27)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:170)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
 at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
 at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
 at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:466)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:299)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:251)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
 ... 83 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:150)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1476)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:174)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:168)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:847)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:106)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:495)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:433)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:815)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1025)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1038)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:402)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1836)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1794)
 at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
 at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1854)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:595)
 at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
 ... 89 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:322)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:840)
 ... 107 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you can try (somewhere in your initaliziation code, before the services are called):

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {new EasyX509TrustManager(null)}, null);
```

You can get the Code for EasyX509TrustManager [here](http://www.jdocs.com/httpclient/3.0.1/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasyX509TrustManager.html)
Or you can provide your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of debugging and trying every solution available on net we finally found the root cause.

We were setting the incorrect password for javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword and javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword properties.

Once you set the correct password this exception will never reappear :) . You can verify the existing settings by simply adding System.getProperties() or System.getProperty(propertyName) statement.

Answer (score -3):

> A looses connection to the webservice

s/loose/lose/g

> saying that "No X509TrustManager
>   implementation available" (see dump
>   below) but Application B, talking to
>   the same server keeps on rocking.

Dropped connections are just a fact of life. Probably App B does a better job at catching and retrying routine errors.

There may be a deeper problem, but it would be good to fix A so an SSL handshake failure doesn't bring down the entire service.

Comment: Downvoted, because the error clearly has nothing to do with dropped connections and a SSL handshake failure.